# Should I select auto-increment and primary key for the same SQL table column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a MySQL table with a primary key column; should I also select the auto-increment option or does primary key already do that?

Comment: You should select both.

Comment: Neither option also does the other option, you should use both together to create a Surrogate (autoincrement) Primary Key.

Comment: Just to clarify that: "... or does primary key already do that?" No, declaring a column as primary key doesn't set it to auto increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely You should select both.
and **the reason why you select both is below**

1. Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically
   when a new record is inserted into a table.

   Often this is the primary key field that we would like to be created
   automatically every time a new record is inserted.